# Android project which has code dependency to a different project library in MonkeyTalk

Tags: android-testing, monkeytalk

I have one main project and one lib project which is dependancy for main project.

I have implement the AspectJ plugin and monkeyTalk agent in main project, then i ran my project and found app splash screen gets hang and app get stopped.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If your android library project contains any resources that you are using in your application project, then you need to apply aspectj weaving to the library as well. Then, clean-build library. Link that to application and follow the normal monkeytalk instrumentation process for the app.

Comment: should i add monkeyagent jar also